# why does the Epoch reset when training SGDClassifier?

Tags: scikit-learn

My understanding of an Epoch is that it's the number of times we have gone through the entire training set during training. But when I train SGDClassifier with verbose=true, I see the below. It just resets after 5 Epochs and begins counting at 1 again. Why would it do that?

Here is how I am instantiating the model:

```
clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier(loss='log', verbose=True)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

And here is the output:

```
-- Epoch 1
Norm: 5.26, NNZs: 448659, Bias: -5.164052, T: 1912007, Avg. loss: 0.005248
Total training time: 0.91 seconds.
-- Epoch 2
Norm: 5.13, NNZs: 448659, Bias: -5.286860, T: 3824014, Avg. loss: 0.004764
Total training time: 1.72 seconds.
-- Epoch 3
Norm: 5.07, NNZs: 448659, Bias: -5.353568, T: 5736021, Avg. loss: 0.004655
Total training time: 2.57 seconds.
-- Epoch 4
Norm: 5.03, NNZs: 448659, Bias: -5.398900, T: 7648028, Avg. loss: 0.004587
Total training time: 3.41 seconds.
-- Epoch 5
Norm: 5.00, NNZs: 448659, Bias: -5.432728, T: 9560035, Avg. loss: 0.004547
Total training time: 4.28 seconds.
-- Epoch 1
Norm: 5.33, NNZs: 448659, Bias: -5.161117, T: 1912007, Avg. loss: 0.009731
Total training time: 0.98 seconds.
-- Epoch 2
Norm: 5.23, NNZs: 448659, Bias: -5.276683, T: 3824014, Avg. loss: 0.009210
Total training time: 1.84 seconds.
```

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: I have updated the question to include code. I'm using a pretty generic setup so there isn't more to it than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats because of implementing a One-vs-Rest Strategy in multi-class problems.

From the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html#classification):

> SGDClassifier supports multi-class classification by combining
>   multiple binary classifiers in a “one versus all” (OVA) scheme. For
>   each of the K classes, a binary classifier is learned that
>   discriminates between that and all other K-1 classes.

So that means if your data has 4 different classes, then 4 different instances of the model will be trained and so each model will print its number of epochs.

The default number of epochs (`max_iter` param) is 5. So each instance will print upto these many epochs.

In a simple binary classification task, only a single model is trained and hence the verbose output will contain single mentions of epochs only.

Hope you understand that now.